# Using JavaScript to replace and increment list components

Tags: javascript

I have a list

```
listOfStrings = ["A1 something bla", "A1 something bla", "A2 something bla", "A2 something bla",]
```

I want to loop through the list and rename every entry to c1v1, c1v2, c2v1, c2v2

I tried:

```
var increment = 1;

for( i = 0; i < listOfStrings.length; i++)
{

listOfStrings.replace(/A1.*/g , 'c1v' + increment);
listOfStrings.replace(/A2.*/g , 'c2v' + increment);

increment++;
```

result was c1v1, c1v2, c2v3, c2v4

Is this possible?

Comment: Hint: Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that you could do

```js
for(i = 1; i < (listOfStrings.length+1); i++) {
  listOfStrings[i-1] = listOfStrings[i-1].replace(/A1.*/g , 'c1v' + i);
}
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of replace back to the array element.

Comment: This will replace the A1 entries but not the A2 entries

Comment: This skips `listOfStrings[0]` and tries to access after the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the individual array elements. And since `replace()` doesn't modify the string in place, you have to assign the result back.

To get the numbering you want, you need a separate counter for replacing `A1...` with `c1v#` and `A2...` with `c2v#`. You can use an object to hold multiple counters, and then use a function to generate the replacement by incrementing the corresponding counter.

```js
const listOfStrings = ["A1 something bla", "A1 something bla", "A2 something bla", "A2 something bla", ]

const counters = {
  1: 0,
  2: 0
};

for (i = 0; i < listOfStrings.length; i++) {
  listOfStrings[i] = listOfStrings[i].replace(/A([12]).*/, (m, num) =>
    'c1v' + ++counters[num]);
}
console.log(listOfStrings);
```

Comment: This looks like what I managed to do, what I want as a result is c1v1, c1v2, c2v1, c2v2 if it's possible. Thank you for trying.

Comment: I've updated the answer to keep separate counters.